# Oracle cursor removes leading zero

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

I have a cursor which selects date from column with NUMBER type containg floating point numbers. Numbers like 4,3433 are returned properly while numbers smaller then 1 have removed leading zero.

For example number 0,4513 is returned as ,4513.

When I execute select used in the cursor on the database, numbers are formatted properly, with leading zeros.

This is how I loop over the recors returned by the cursor:

```
FOR c_data IN cursor_name(p_date) LOOP

...

END LOOP;
```

Any ideas why it works that way?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the default number formatting that Oracle provides.
If you want to specify something custom, you shall use TO_CHAR function (either in SQL query or PL/SQL code inside the loop).

Here is how it works:

```
SQL>
SQL> WITH aa AS (
  2  select 1.3232 NUM from dual UNION ALL
  3  select 1.3232 NUM from dual UNION ALL
  4  select 332.323 NUM from dual UNION ALL
  5  select 0.3232 NUM from dual
  6  )
  7  select  NUM, to_char(NUM, 'FM999990D9999999') FORMATTED from aa
  8  /

       NUM FORMATTED
---------- ---------------
    1.3232 1.3232
    1.3232 1.3232
   332.323 332.323
     .3232 0.3232

SQL>
```

In this example, 'FM' - suppresses extra blanks, '0' indicates number digit including leading/trailing zeros, and '9' indicates digit suppressing leading/trailing zeros.

You can find many examples here:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34570

Answer (score 4):

You're confusing number format and number value.

The two strings `0.123` and `.123`, when read as a number, are mathematically equals. They represent the same number. In Oracle the true number representation is never displayed directly, we always convert a number to a character to display it, either implicitly or [explicitly with a function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17209/functions211.htm#i79330).

You assume that a number between 0 and 1 should be represented with a leading 0, but this is not true by default, it depends on how you ask this number to be displayed. If you don't want unexpected outcome, [you have to be explicit](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17209/sql_elements004.htm#i34510) when displaying numbers/dates, for example:

```
to_char(your_number, '9990.99');
```